# Python thread management modules

Tags: python, multithreading

what is the best module in python for multi thread management ?

1.Create N number of threads
   2.Assigning work to thread if it is free
   3.Getting the status of the thread
   4.killing a thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the threading module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading

You could also use concurrent.futures

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Keep in mind that Python doesn't support true threading because of the global interpreter lock. As a result you would typically use threading for IO bound tasks.

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

If you could be a little more specific with what you are trying to accomplish in # 1-4 I could give an applicable example.

Comment: concurrent futures works good for threading and multiprocess